# JQuery placing elements X pixels by degree (Basic trig)

Tags: trigonometry

Essentially I want to place an element X pixels from the current position towards the center. Here's my code:

```
var sitX = parseInt($('div.par[id='+my+']').css("left"))+43; //43 is half the width
    var sitY = parseInt($('div.par[id='+my+']').css("top"))+43; //43 is half the height
var deltaY = sitY - 200; //200 is the vertical center of the screen
var deltaX = sitX - 380; //Same for the horizontal
ang1 = Math.atan(deltaY / deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI;
...
```

I later create it with `right=(Math.cos(ang1)*60)` and `top=(Math.sin(ang1)*60)` on an element with absolute positioning.

What am I missing?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mgfVR/1/

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, you'd probably get a better answer on Stack Overflow.

Anyway, the error I'm seeing is that the `Math.cos()` and `Math.sin()` functions [should take arguments in radians](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288153/jquery-trigonmetry), so you don't need the `*180/Math.PI` in the definition of `ang1`.